# Get PHP Var_Dump Output in XML

Tags: php, xml, soap-client, var-dump

I am using SoapClient to return data from a Web Service provider. The data is returned in a typical object/array PHP format. I want to return it in XML.

Here is my code to call the Web Service (I have omitted my username and password):

```
<?php
//Calling Chrome ADS with Build Data
 $client = new     SoapClient('http://services.chromedata.com/Description/7b?wsdl');
 $account = ['number'=>"", 'secret'=>"", 'country'=>"US",    'language'=>"en"];
 $switch =  ["ShowAvailableEquipment", "ShowExtendedTechnicalSpecifications", "ShowExtendedDescriptions"];
 $vin = $_POST["b12"];

 $result = $client->describeVehicle([
 'accountInfo' => $account,
 'switch' => $switch,
  'vin' => $vin
]);

var_dump ($result);

 ?>
```

Here is how the data is currently outputted:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (18) {
  ["responseStatus"]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (2) {
    ["responseCode"]=>
    string(10) "Successful"
    ["description"]=>
    string(10) "Successful"
  }
  ["vinDescription"]=>
   object(stdClass)#4 (11) {
    ["WorldManufacturerIdentifier"]=>
    string(17) "Germany Audi Nsu "
    ["restraintTypes"]=>
    array(5) {
      [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#5 (3) {
    ["group"]=>
    object(stdClass)#6 (2) {
      ["_"]=>
      string(6) "Safety"
      ["id"]=>
      int(9)
    }
    ["header"]=>
    object(stdClass)#7 (2) {
      ["_"]=>
      string(17) "Air Bag - Frontal"
      ["id"]=>
      int(38)
    }
    ["category"]=>
    object(stdClass)#8 (2) {
      ["_"]=>
      string(14) "Driver Air Bag"
      ["id"]=>
      int(1001)
    }
  }
```

Here is how I want the data to be outputted (this is from when I run the request through SoapUI):

```
  <VehicleDescription country="US" language="en" modelYear="2008" bestMakeName="Audi" bestModelName="S4" bestStyleName="5dr Avant Wgn" xmlns="urn:description7b.services.chrome.com">
     <responseStatus responseCode="Successful" description="Successful"/>
     <vinDescription vin="WAUUL78E38A092113" modelYear="2008" division="Audi" modelName="S4" styleName="5dr Avant Wgn" bodyType="Wagon 4 Dr." drivingWheels="AWD" builddata="no">
        <WorldManufacturerIdentifier>Germany Audi Nsu</WorldManufacturerIdentifier>
        <restraintTypes>
           <group id="9">Safety</group>
           <header id="38">Air Bag - Frontal</header>
           <category id="1001">Driver Air Bag</category>
        </restraintTypes>
        <restraintTypes>
           <group id="9">Safety</group>
           <header id="38">Air Bag - Frontal</header>
           <category id="1002">Passenger Air Bag</category>
        </restraintTypes>
        <restraintTypes>
           <group id="9">Safety</group>
           <header id="39">Air Bag - Side</header>
           <category id="1005">Front Side Air Bag</category>
        </restraintTypes>
        <restraintTypes>
           <group id="9">Safety</group>
           <header id="39">Air Bag - Side</header>
           <category id="1007">Front Head Air Bag</category>
        </restraintTypes>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [__getLastResponse](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastresponse.php)

> Returns the XML received in the last SOAP response.

```
<?php
$client = SoapClient("http://services.chromedata.com/Description/7b?wsdl", array('trace' => 1));
$account = ['number'=>"", 'secret'=>"", 'country'=>"US",    'language'=>"en"];
$switch =  ["ShowAvailableEquipment", "ShowExtendedTechnicalSpecifications", "ShowExtendedDescriptions"];
$vin = $_POST["b12"];

$result = $client->describeVehicle([
    'accountInfo' => $account,
    'switch' => $switch,
    'vin' => $vin
]);

//htmlentitites just to see the result in the browser window
echo "Response :<br/>", htmlentities($client->__getLastResponse()), "<br/>";
?>
```

Comment: Only receiving the output `Response:` when I include that. Tried `echo "Response :<br/>", htmlentities($soapClient->__getLastResponse()), "<br/>";` and `echo "Response :<br/>", htmlentities($client->__getLastResponse()), "<br/>";`

Comment: did you setted `'trace' => true`?

Comment: That was it, many thanks!

Comment: No problem. You can mark the answer as accepted if it works for you.

Comment: If I want the `$result` variable to be in xml where `var_dump $result;` would output xml how would I manipulate the `$result` variable to achieve that?Something like `$result -> htmlentities($client->__getLastResponse());` ?